# Logging in MariaDB in Centos

Tags: mysql, centos, mariadb

I am using Centos 6.5 and have just installed `MariaDB-sever` and `MariaDB-client` a while ago.

The first problem is that I start MariaDB by the command `/etc/init.d/mysqld start` instead of `/etc/init.d/mysql start` (because there is no `mysql` file in `init.d`). So currently I am baffled because I don't know what  I started is MySql or MariaDB.

That leads to the second problem. According to their Knowledge base, I tried `mysql -u root -p` to log in. But  it displayed `MySql` instead of `MariaDB`, about which I feel wrong:

```
Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 5
Server version: 5.1.73 Source distribution

MySQL [(none)] >
```

So, am I running MariaDB or MySQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, what you have started is wrong - it is running MySQL 5.1.73. You should uninstall your "distribution" provided MySQL (which ships with CentOS 6.5) and just install MariaDB.

You can do this by looking at: rpm -qa |grep -i mysql and removing those packages. Just do a clean install of MariaDB and you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Some distributions ship /etc/init.d/mysqld, some - /etc/init.d/mysql . It makes no difference, just different script names.

MariaDB origins from MySQL, so if you see MariaDB in the prompt then it's MariaDB. You will never see MariaDB in Oracle's MySQL.